# push rejected - failed to compile monorepo app

Tags: heroku, git-push, monorepo

I am trying to deploy my node.js application to heroku using git remote. These are the steps I have taken:

```
$ cd /path/to/app/folder
$ heroku git:remote -a name_of_app
$ git add.
$ git commit 'testcommit'
$ git push heroku master
```

I am using the heroku-buildpack-monorepo, but this is where it fails. I keep getting following errorlog:

```
Enumerating objects: 264, done.
Counting objects: 100% (264/264), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (232/232), done.
Writing objects: 100% (264/264), 14.84 MiB | 867.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 264 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Updated 176 paths from 8717588
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. https://github.com/lstoll/heroku-buildpack-monorepo
remote:        2. heroku-community/multi-procfile
remote:        3. mars/create-react-app
remote: -----> Monorepo app detected
remote: mv: cannot stat '/tmp/build_d0df8c13/app/': No such file or directory
remote:       FAILED to copy directory into place
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Monorepo app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: cf9d7091a8d7f456baa34ca4b0c046abbbca3fb5
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version cf9d7091a8d7f456baa34ca4b0c046abbbca3fb5
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to taalportfolio-app.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/taalportfolio-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/taalportfolio-app.git'
```

Any ideas what I should do to complete the push?